# Find the velocity and acceleration of a pulley in a mass-spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, spring

Given below system. We know the Hooke's constant of the spring is $k$. the mass of the box under the pulley is $m$. The mass of the pulley is $M$. The radius of the pulley is $R$. Radius of gyration is $R_g$, where $R_g$ is close but not equal to $R$.

We release the system from the static state. When the spring is extended by $L$, what's the the velocity and acceleration of the pulley?

This looks like a classical setup but I can't find a solution. We can calculate the energy of the system by looking at the work done by the gravity and the spring. But how do we divide the energy between the kinetic energy of the pulley and the rotation of the pulley?

[image]

Comment: Don't know why this got closed. I think it is a good question.

Comment: @LeoLiu I know, and why do they even have a homework and exercise tag if that's disallowed.

Comment: I think your problem got solved on physics forums. You might want to check your thread.